# Copy list of files to specific folder locations

Tags: file, batch-file, copy

I have ~10,000 files in one folder. I want to copy specific files to specific folders based on a text file. Is it possible to use a semicolon delimited text file where the first part of each line is the source path & file name and the second part is the destination path?

C:\Files\File1.txt;C:\Folder1
C:\Files\File2.txt;C:\Folder2
C:\Files\File3.txt;C:\FolderN\

What would the code look like? Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

I have an existing bat file I use to copy all of the files listed in a text file to one specific folder location (below) but in this case I need to send different files to different folders and I would rather not run my bat file 50 times, changing the destination path in the bat file each time...

for /f %%f in (%1) do (
copy %%f G:\Files\PutFilesHere
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "usebackq delims=; tokens=1,2" %%I in (`type filelist.txt`) do (
    copy /y %%I %%J
)
goto :eof
```

The `for` loop is told to use the result of a command (`usebackq`, for command `type filelist.txt`), to split at each `;`, and to take elements #1 and #2. The fist is named as the variable (`%%I`, take care, case sensitive), and the second is the next letter, so `%%J`.
Then, the copy is trivial.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept answer then, it may help people later if they see that there is an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2delims=;" %%f in (%1) do ( copy "%%f" "%%g" )
```

see `for /?` from the prompt for documentation